# How to view the features of a point with a click in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am developing a plug-in for QGIS. I am creating a form of personalized editing using QtCreator. The form is in the following image

[image]

I read a csv file and when i click in a button OK I get a layer with any desired points

My goal: When I click on the "SELECT POINT" I want plot  a graph with the point attributes.
I see this code

```
   class nameform:
    """QGIS Plugin Implementation."""

    def __init__(self, iface):

        self.iface = iface
        self.dlg.pushButtonContour.clicked.connect(self.open_contour)


        self.canvas = self.iface.mapCanvas()

    def open_graph(self):
        self.pointEmitter = QgsMapToolEmitPoint(self.iface.mapCanvas())
        QObject.connect( self.pointEmitter, SIGNAL("canvasClicked(const QgsPoint, Qt::MouseButton)"), self.selectNow)
        self.iface.mapCanvas().setMapTool( self.pointEmitter )  

    def selectNow(self, point, button):
        layer = self.iface.activeLayer()
        if not layer or layer.type() != QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            QMessageBox.warning(None, "No!", "Select a vector layer")
            return
        width = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapUnitsPerPixel() * 2
        rect = QgsRectangle(point.x() - width, point.y() - width, point.x() + width, point.y() + width)
        rect = self.iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().mapToLayerCoordinates(layer, rect)
        layer.select([], rect)
        feat = QgsFeature()
        ids = []
        while layer.nextFeature(feat):
            ids.append( feat.id() )
        layer.setSelectedFeatures( ids )
```

But i have a error. When i click in select point and i pick in the point gives me this error

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QgsVectorLayer.select(QgsRectangle, bool): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'list'
  QgsVectorLayer.select(unknown-type): too many arguments
```

Comment: **TypeError** is suggesting to change `layer.select([], rect)` for `layer.select(rect, True)`.