# Adding sequence value on attribute table when clicking point in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, sequential

I have a point shapefiles that has a specific column name "Record".

In QGIS I want to add a sequence value in this column from 1, 2, 3,... so on until the last when I click each point one by one (the values added automatically).

In QGIS when the common method was in Toogle Edit we select a point then open the Attribute Table and manually type the value in specific column but how could I do this automatically ?

Comment: Have a read of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162423/how-to-view-the-features-of-a-point-with-a-click-in-qgis, what you're after is similar to this with an incrementer...

Comment: Thanks Michael, for this code I would like to learn it later. Do you have any idea about any existing plugin or processing toolbox that would help me with this?

Comment: No, I don't know of any plugins like this, there might not be one that I'm not aware of so check the repository https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ for something close and tweak it to your needs. It's a fairly specific requirement you have so there's not likely to be an out-of-the-box solution. If you just want unique ascending numbers and aren't fussy about the order you could calculate $rownum into your Record field; it's the clicking to assign that is the hard part.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Yes it might be something with specific treatment because I need the value added up based on my click on each point.

Comment: which QGIS version?

Comment: I am using QGIS 2.18.15. Is it any new features in QGIS 3.0 regarding my question?